# Execute code before the called function is executed

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to mark a function somehow (attributes maybe?) so that when it's called from anywhere, some other code gets to process the parameters and return a value instead of the called function, or can let the function execute normally.

I would use it for easy caching.

For example, if I had a function called Add10 and it would look like this:

```
int Add10 (int n)
{
    return n + 10;
}
```

If the function go called repeatedly with the same value (Add10(7)) it would always give the same result (17) so it makes no sense to recalculate every time. Naturally, I wouldn't do it with functions as simple as this but I'm sure you can understand what I mean.

Does C# provide any way of doing what I want?
I need a way to mark a function as cached so that when someone does Add10(16) some code somewhere is ran first to check in a dictionary is we already know the Add10 value of 16 and return it if we do, calculate, store and return if we don't.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180242/generating-a-unique-cache-key-based-on-method-arguments

Comment: There is alot of threads on this here at stackoverflow, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929540/is-there-anyway-to-cache-function-method-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to memoize the function. Here's one way:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/26/function-memoization.aspx

Comment: The link is unfortunately broken and it looks like that this post was deleted. At least it is not in this list from wesdyer 01/2007 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wesdyer/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the function, then I would expose a `Func<>` **delegate**:

```
Func<int, int> add10 = (n) =>
{
    // do some other work
    ...

    int result = Add10(n); // calling actual function

    // do some more perhaps even change result
    ...

    return result;

};
```

And then:

```
int res = add10(5); // invoking the delegate rather than calling function
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason mentioned, you probably want something like *function memoization*.

Heres another SO thread about it:
[Whose responsibility is it to cache / memoize function results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328895/whose-responsibility-is-it-to-cache-memoize-function-results)

You could also achieve this sort of functionality using principles related to Aspect Oriented Programming.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx

[Aspect Oriented Programming in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

[MbCache](http://code.google.com/p/mbcache) might be what you're looking for.